# Embedded database to neo4j desktop

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm currently using `DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder` to store `neo4j` data on my local host. Is there anyway to import the data to `neo4j` desktop or any other tool for visualisation? for example by creating a `.csv` file or dumping the data.

This is how my directories look like.

first
[image: first]

second
[image: second]

third
[image: third]

I tried to replace the `/data` directory in a `neo4j` desktop database with my own `/data` directory but it didn't work (`neo4j` desktop kept giving an error which was no surprise).

[enter image description here][4]

this is my code for connecting
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkIKu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is Neo4j Browser is that you're interested in, not Neo4j Desktop. Most straightforward way is to connect Neo4j Browser to your embedded database while your app is running. But also indeed you can export whole database to a file and import it in Neo4j Browser which is connected to some other db, preferably empty.

### Connect from Neo4j Browser in Neo4j Desktop

If you have started Neo4j Embedded with these settings:

```
.setConfig( BoltConnector.enabled, true )`
.setConfig(BoltConnector.encryption_level, BoltConnector.EncryptionLevel.DISABLED)
```

then you can connect to it while application is running by pointing Neo4j Browser to localhost:7687 and `No authentication` option:

[image: connect to db with neo4j browser in neo4j desktop]

---

### Connect from Neo4j Browser in Docker Neo4j image

If you have **Docker**, you can access database created by your application without application itself and without *Neo4j Desktop* installed.

If you are creating your embedded db like that:

```
DatabaseManagementService managementService = 
    new  DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder(new File("target/mydb").toPath())
```

it means database is located at `/target/mydb/` directory. It stays there even after application is stopped.

You can run a new neo4j server with this database by executing this bash command in directory with `pom.xml` once your application is stopped:

```
sudo docker run --rm -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 -v $PWD/target/mydb/data:/data --name neo4j-1 neo4j
```

I am using powershell and actual commands I execute are:

```
$neo4jDataDir = './target/mydb/data/'
docker run --name neo4j-1 --rm -v $neo4jDataDir`:/data -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 -e NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/qwertyuiop -d neo4j
# Checkout what's happening:
docker logs neo4j-1
# Stop server:
docker stop neo4j-1
```

Once server is up and running, **Neo4j Browser** becomes available at localhost:7474 in web browser.

Also I've noticed when you stop server, **Neo4j Browser** keeps working until you will close it's tab in web browser.

### Export database and import in Neo4j Browser

If for some reason you can't connect to your database with Neo4j Browser, you can dump your db to a file and import it afterwards in Neo4j Browser which is connected to a different db, preferably empty. For this you will need external plugin Apoc.

1. Add these dependencies to project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.procedure</groupId>
    <artifactId>apoc-core</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.procedure</groupId>
    <artifactId>apoc-common</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Register procedure you will use:

```java
...
GraphDatabaseService db = graphDb.database(GraphDatabaseSettings.DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME);
registerProcedure(db,
        apoc.export.cypher.ExportCypher.class);
...
public static void registerProcedure(GraphDatabaseService db, Class<?>... procedures) {
    GlobalProcedures globalProcedures = ((GraphDatabaseAPI) db).getDependencyResolver()
            .resolveDependency(GlobalProcedures.class);
    for (Class<?> procedure : procedures) {
        try {
            globalProcedures.registerProcedure(procedure);
            globalProcedures.registerFunction(procedure);
            globalProcedures.registerAggregationFunction(procedure);
        } catch (KernelException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("while registering " + procedure, e);
        }
    }
}
```

3. Enable exporting to a file:

```java
ApocConfig.apocConfig().setProperty(ApocConfig.APOC_EXPORT_FILE_ENABLED, true);
```

4. Execute procedure:

```java
try (
    var driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.none());
    var session = driver.session()) {
    var query = """
            CALL apoc.export.cypher.all("all-plain.cypher", {
                format: "plain",
                useOptimizations: {type: "UNWIND_BATCH", unwindBatchSize: 20}
            })
            """;
    session.executeRead(t -> t.run(query).consume());
}
```

5. Find a `./target/mydb/all-plain.cypher` text file with all your data in Cypher format.
6. Drag and drop it to Neo4j Browser or copy-paste it's contents.

Fully working example of dumping database to a file can be found [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Podbrushkin/3f16feb9b9da22ab27ee2878c38633aa).

Comment: I faced this error: ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3.
I couldnt resolve using methods available on the internet.

Comment: Make sure in webapp `BoltConnector.enabled = true`, also you can add a line with `BoltConnector.listen_address` as in gif with port explicitly specified, and in **Neo4j Browser** make sure you're choosing links of type `bolt://` and port is correct. Also you can try explicitly specifying username and password while creating db (instead of `no auth`), I remember it helped me once - under some circumstances `no auth` wasn't working and I had to switch to username+password auth.

Comment: thank you. I connected but I can't find my data there I also added my code image.

Comment: If you're using Docker possibly you've mounted wrong directory to `/data/`. Examine docker command and make sure in `-v $PWD/target/mydb/data:/data` part before colon there is correct path to existing db. In my case it's `./target/mydb/data` (when I'm in dir with pom.xml) but in yours it would be `./target/neo4j-CyGraph-db/data`. Also please next time if you want to attach some code - attach it in form of markdown code block, not screenshot.

Comment: I am not using docker. Would you explain what you mean by existing DB? Should I set the directory "/target/neo4j-CyGraph-db/data" somewhere in neo4j? Is there anyway that I can simply dump my embedded db from java into a certain (e.g., csv) form that can be used by neo4j browser?

Comment: If you're saying "I can't find my data" it means there is a database with some data (nodes and relationships) you've inserted into it. I'm referring to it as "existing db". If you're not using docker, `/target/../data` dir is not relevant for you. Can you access your data right in your application? I.e. execute `match (n) return n` and see some nodes and rels you've created earlier. Can you upload your app to github ot github.gists?

Comment: My application shows the graph correctly. Here is the gist (https://gist.github.com/AESTheProgrammer/55c226197a31243e9f99ee091047fe1e)